# How do I configure gitlab-ci.yml for a simple hello world program in Gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I wanted to know how to configure the correct `.gitlab-ci.yml` file so that it'll automatically detect errors within the code that I've committed into my project.

for example I will create a new python file `helloworld.py`:

```
print("hello world""
```

There is a clear error within the code above, and I want my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to be able to test that code and make sure it will not pass.

How do I do this guys? I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to execute the script in a linter:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: ubuntu

hello-test:
    script: 
        - apt-get update && apt-get install -y pylint3
        - pylint3 helloworld.py
```

Or execute it in an interpreter directly:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: ubuntu

hello-test:
    script: 
        - apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3
        - python3 helloworld.py
```

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you for your response. I've copied the code above into my gitlab-ci.yml. I've created a new file within my project called helloworld.py and within it I put                 print("hello world") The code is fine but its still failed the test :-( any help?

Comment: The GitLab runner should give you some output and tell you why it failed. The linter will not only check whether the code is syntactically correct, but also whether it conforms to Python coding style and practices. How much `pylint` test is configurable. I added a version using only the interpreter. Ideally you run a true coverage test.

Comment: Hi Jan, I've modified my yml file by copy pasting your code into the file. But the correct print("hello world") code will wouldnt pass the test. It only says ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1. any other suggestions?

Comment: might failed, because && apt-get install python3 asks for input (Y or N) 
This will block it from running
if you modify to "apt-get update && apt-get install python3 -y " , this runs smoothly

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following codes:

```
stages:
  - build

PythonBuild:
  stage: build
  script:
    - python helloworld.py
```

---

BTW, if you want to check all python files, you can add a shell script to help you do this.

**bash.sh**

```
#! bin/sh
for n in `find . -name "*.py"`
do
  python $n
done
```

then edit **.gitlab-ci.yml** as following:

```
stages:
  - build

PythonBuild:
  stage: build
  script:
    - bash build.sh
```

: remeber to push **build.bash** to root path of your gitlab repository with **.gitlab-ci.yml**.

Comment: The OP probably wants to write Python3 code, so he should use `python3` interpreter.

Comment: it works!!!! the test managed to failed my code and it showed the error. Thank you

Comment: Now how can use this yml code for multiple python file that I commit into my project: e.g helloworld.py and test.py

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I think it depends on environment of gitlab-runner, if anything you want to use in .gitlab-ci.yml, you should install them to server of gitlab-runner. install of using command in .gitlab-ci.yml. that's not a best try I think.

Comment: @EndisSapuandi I have edited my advice, please check it :)

Comment: Hi @soolaugust Thank you so much for your help, I've managed to do it. However, is it possible to only check only one python code that is committed without the .yml also running the other python codes in the repository?

Comment: @EndisSapuandi Hi, I'm sorry that I didn't try like this before. because in my opinion, when you commit (add or update python files), you should check all to ensure your source codes is correct as expect. So about your requirement, I am sorry I don't know how to do with that.

Comment: @soolaugust That is fine, you have helped me a lot and I really appreciate it. Thank you :D Do you know how to allow modules to be installed within CI. For example; in my code i put install pandas as pd, i've tried it but it wasnt able to run pandas.

Comment: @EndisSapuandi, as gitlab CI is running by gitlab-runner. So if you could access the serve where gitlab-runner running on. You can install pandas there.

Comment: @soolaugust I am currently using the browser version of gitlab. Do you know where I can install modules on?

Comment: @EndisSapuandi, maybe you should add `- apt-get install pip && pip install pandas` in your .gitlab-ci.yml. I am not familiar with browser version. but you can try this.